# how to sign message in solana-web3.js?

Tags: javascript, web3js, solana, solana-web3js

i want to sign message in solana-web3.js but i can't find signMessage function like the one in [phantom extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72414999/how-to-verify-the-signature-of-a-message-in-phantom-solana)

using phantom extension will give result like this:

```
{"signature":"5uLfqwr19GdFBUyMTPeeL3HJ9U5f9TjRzAnCkzAaCyxZgNeA3C1i6c37FjPTowZRg8WSYdwANdVVXMMkWx2Hzwoy","address":"2o6AxcaMZqcS3L8oyPhS66keuxA1FrRtrSRcRxRw4U9C"}
```

i found the code but this code doesn't give the same result as signMessage function of phantom wallet extension

```
const signMessage = (message, mnemonic) => {
// mnemonic to keypair
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
const path = 'm/44\'/501\'/0\'/0\'';
const derivedSeed = derivePath(path, seed.toString('hex')).key;
const keyPair = Keypair.fromSeed(derivedSeed);
if (!keyPair) throw new Error('Invalid secret key')
// sign message
const address = keyPair.publicKey.toBase58()
const bufSecretKey = keyPair.secretKey
const serializedData = Buffer.from(message)
const bufSig = tweetnacl.sign(serializedData, bufSecretKey)
const signature = Buffer.from(bufSig).toString('hex')

return { signature, address}
```

};

the result of the above code is like this:

```
{"signature":"f53409d847b5eae5ef3bb892b998805d2ea04b699e39bb5c126e757d1f4023488945ba210609fb661f70c10a45fdd55db09741d5e6a8839446a91af39d4fe5044c6f67696e204368616c6c656e67653a2066613666363234342d663863352d343162642d383033372d356333396562653534396366","address":"2o6AxcaMZqcS3L8oyPhS66keuxA1FrRtrSRcRxRw4U9C"}
```

how do i sign like in phantom wallet extension with solana-web3.js???

Comment: Looks like they provide signature in base58 format. 
So you should do `base58.encode(Buffer.from(bufSig())` to get signature in the same format.
base58 is from npm package `import bs58 from "bs58";`